# Which port should I use for node js in ispmanager?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tied the domain to the panel, in the server.js I output this and try to connect to the socket does not work. I tried different ports, even the one in the instructions: process.env.SOCKET does not work. Please tell me what to do to work in isp for a year

```
const { Server } = require('ws');
const socket = process.env.SOCKET;
const server = new Server({ port: socket });
server.on('connection', function connection(ws, request, client) {
      console.log('connect');
      client.send('connect');
});
```

https://docs.ispmanager.com/ispmanager6-lite/node-js

Comment: Did you set the SOCKET in the .env file?

Comment: @MohammedSaber I 'm new to node js. I don't know where this file is, but in Ispmanager, the instructions do so. And I don 't have a slave

Comment: Please take a look at the following link: https://www.codementor.io/@parthibakumarmurugesan/what-is-env-how-to-set-up-and-run-a-env-file-in-node-1pnyxw9yxj